# ignore_sticky_posts not working with word press version 3.9.1

Tags: sticky-post

I am trying to display a sticky post by its category id. The sticky post is displayed, but the problem is that the published sticky post is displayed twice.

You can see from the snap shot below that the same sticky post is displayed twice (it is highlighted with the blue arrow). I don't want to display the sticky title news in the sub tittle of sticky news.

You can see in bellow snap. These are same news the first arrow is sticky I have set from backend and second arrow is the same news displaying bellow the sticky see here I don’t want display second arrow news its twice here I wanted to display another news except the second arrow News.

[image: sticky]

Bellow is the code to set sticky from widget post

```
<ul>
<?php 

$args = array(
            'category_name' => 'maharashtra',
            'post__in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
            'showposts' => '1',

        );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
  <li>      <div class="thumbnail_class"><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(342,173), array ('class' => 'alignleft1')); ?></a></div>
        <div class="link_contect"><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div><li>
      <?php 
    endwhile;

?>
</ul>
```

Bellow is the my sample code to display the recent post.

```
<div class="home-post home-post-first green">
<h2><a href="http://majhapaper.com/test/विभाग/महाराष्ट्र/">महाराष्ट्र</a></h2>
<?php 
$recent = new WP_Query("cat=255&showposts=6&ignore_sticky_posts=1"); 

?>

<ul>
<?php

    while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post(); 
$postvariable++;

if ($postvariable == 1) {
 ?>
<li>[widget id="text-8"]</li>
<?php  
} else { ?>
<li>            
            <div class="link_contect"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

            </div>
```

Comment: I think we are going in circles here. I might have misunderstood you, in your pic, the first title inside the green area just below your pic, you want that title gone?

Comment: Yes you are right I want it display one time on the up side as sticky news but it display 2time pointed with blue arrow are the same news I want it only one on up side like pic

Comment: `showposts` is depredciated, you should be using `posts_per_page`

Comment: Are `category_name` 'maharashtra' and `cat` ID 255 the same category, or are these diffirent categories all together. Sorry for asking so much questions, but I'm still in the dark a bit. One more thing, what is `[widget id="text-8"]`

Comment: [widget id="text-8"] is shord code to display sticky from widget

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to totally remove the sticky posts from the query, you need to use `post__not_in`.
The Codex has an example, which you can adapt to your needs:

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$args = array(
    'cat' => 3,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'post__not_in' => $sticky,
    'paged' => $paged
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts

`ignore_sticky_posts` doesn't remove sticky posts from the query; it just ignores the fact that they are sticky, and lists them in their natural position.

Comment: if i used the post__not_in insted of post__in i am not able set stcky from the widget

Comment: I'm referring to the second loop, not the first. You can set `post__in` for the first loop (your sticky post) and `post__not_in` (replacing `ignore_sticky_posts`) for the second.

Comment: your code is working but i am not able to display my first post bellow the stick otherwise code is good

Comment: i am using this code code is working but having one issue its not displaying the first post it displaying from second post  that the issue other wise your answer is good.see the bellow code which i have used

Comment: <ul>
<?php
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$args = array(
    'cat' => 255,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
   'post__not_in' => $sticky,
  
    showposts=>6
);
$recent= new WP_Query( $args );
 while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post(); 
$postvariable++;

if ($postvariable == 1) {
 ?>
<li>[widget id="text-8"]</li>
<?php 
} else { 
 
?>
<li>
   <div class="link_contect"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

   </div>
 </li>
<?php
}

?>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>

Comment: But it's not showing the sticky post, is it? That was the question. Maybe you need to start another question. BTW as @Pieter Goosen says, `showposts`is depreciated. Also, formatting your code really helps with readability!

Comment: yes from next i will be careful to better code formating